# How to style button CSS in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I made an input:

```
  <div class="button-row">
              <button md-icon-button><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></button>
              <button md-icon-button><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>
            </div>
```

Now it looks as plain button, without styles. How to style this? I tried to add styles:

```
// Import Angular Material
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css";
```

Comment: are you using Angular CLI?

Comment: No, simple application

Comment: Have you included the css to your angular-cli.json? Have you installed the material package trough angular cli or manually?

Comment: @user8376580 The OP already stated that he doesn't use Angular CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing the prebuilt stylesheet to your projecnt, you need to add `color` property in `<md-button>` which is either `primary`, `accent` or `warn`.

```
<div class="button-row">
  <button color="primary" md-icon-button><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i></button>
  <button color="warn" md-icon-button><i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i></button>
</div>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rne0tm4q8FikAMY8r4le?p=preview)

If import doesn't work, you can try adding this CDN in `index.html`:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Problem is that it is work for remaining elements from material?

Comment: You mean the prebuilt theme is working for least elements? And what do you mean by least elements?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `Angular CLI` you can simply include prebuilt css in your index.html file

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The path depends on your app setup.